# TypeScript, generics and instanceof

Tags: typescript, inheritance, assertion, instanceof

I have the following code:

```
abstract class BaseToken {}

class OpenParen extends BaseToken {
    public static assert(t: BaseToken): OpenParen {
        if (t instanceof OpenParen) {
            return t;
        } else {
            throw typeAssertionError;
        }
    }
}

class CloseParen extends BaseToken {
    public static assert(t: BaseToken): CloseParen {
        if (t instanceof CloseParen) {
            return t;
        } else {
            throw typeAssertionError;
        }
    }
}
```

The `assert` functions can be used to check whether a given instance of `BaseToken` is in fact a certain specialization of it.

```
const t: BaseToken = getTokenFromSomewhere();
const oparen = OpenParen.assert(t); // type of oparen is OpenParen, exception if not
```

As there are many more classes other than `OpenParen` and `CloseParen` derived from `BaseToken`, this is obviously a lot of boilerplate. I'd like to move the implementation of `assert` into the base class. The following does not work:

```
abstract class BaseToken {
    public static assert<T>(t: BaseToken): T {
        if (t instanceof T) { // T used as a value here
            return t;
        } else {
            throw typeAssertionError;
        }
    }
}

class OpenParen extends BaseToken {}
class CloseParen extends BaseToken {}
```

The problem is that on the one hand, this doesn't compile as `instanceof` requires a value, not a class, and on the other hand, this approach does not bind `T` to the subclass type, so `OpenParen.assert` would still be a generic.

I believe that I could achieve this in C++ with the *Curiously recurring template pattern* (CRTP), but that doesn't work in TypeScript. Is there some other trick to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a static method, `this` should refer to the current constructor being used, so the implementation should just check `t instanceof this`.

Getting the typings to work out is trickier.  One problem is that there is no [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) for static methods; see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).  You'd like to be able to say that `assert()` returns a value of the instance type of the constructor you're calling it on.  For *instance* methods you could say that it returns the type named `this`... but there's no analogous `this` type for static methods.

There are workarounds, however.  Here's one possible way to do it:

```
abstract class BaseToken {
    public static assert<T extends BaseToken>(this: new (...args: any) => T, t: BaseToken): T {
        if (t instanceof this) {
            return t;
        } else {
            throw new Error("YOU DID A BAD THING");
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are making `assert` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) method where the type parameter `T` is intended to be the instance type of whatever subclass is being used.  And we are using a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) to tell the compiler that the you will only call `assert()` on a constructor object that constructs `T` instances.

---

Let's test it out:

```
class OpenParen extends BaseToken {
    someProp = 123;
}

class CloseParen extends BaseToken {
    otherProp = "abc";
}

const openP: BaseToken = new OpenParen();
const closeP: BaseToken = new CloseParen();

console.log(OpenParen.assert(openP).someProp.toFixed(2)); // 123.00
console.log(CloseParen.assert(closeP).otherProp.toUpperCase()) // ABC
```

Both `openP` and `closeP` are known to the compiler only as `BaseToken`s, but `OpenParen.assert(openP)` and `OpenParen.assert(closedP)` returns `OpenParen` and `CloseParen` respectively, and you can access the subclass-specific properties I added to demonstrate that this works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

There's a solution that doesn't require an instance. It has still not the exact syntax you want but at least achieves the same this time.

(Credits for the `Constructor` type to https://www.simonholywell.com/post/typescript-constructor-type.html)

```
type Constructor<T extends {} = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function isOfConstructor<T>(cns: Constructor<T>, b: BaseToken): b is T{
    return cns.prototype === b.constructor.prototype;
}

function assert<T>(cns: Constructor<T>, b: BaseToken) : T{
    if (isOfConstructor(cns, b)){
        return b;
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("not of that type");
    }
}

// then call it with
assert(OpenParen, getTokenFromSomewhere());
```

### Original "non-static" solution

If you don't need `assert` to be static you can get away with

```
abstract class BaseToken{
    private hasSameTypeAs<T extends BaseToken>(t: BaseToken): t is T{
        return t.constructor.prototype === this.constructor.prototype;
    }

    public assert<T extends BaseToken>(t: T): T {
        if (this.hasSameTypeAs(t)) {
            return t;
        } else {
            throw new Error("foo");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ehm, unfortunately that's not what I want, because this requires two instance, one to call assert on and the other to pass as argument. But I have only one instance and want to ensure it has the proper type, or fail.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure you can do that in TS as most of TS specific code is removed when transpiled to JS for execution

Here [https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516] you can see proposal of abstracting statics bur for now - you need to do it a bit around.

For now i would add this to your BaseToken class

```
  public static assert<T>(t: T extends BaseToken<T>): T {
    throw new Error('[abstract BaseToken method .assert] called');
  };
```

PS: Yours idea of static class executing non-static method will fail at start, even for yours idea there you need at least one empty instance of each of classes to be able to call non-static method from static ones.

Comment: I don't understand how this could help my problem. I still need to override this in the subclass as this function will always throw.

Comment: This makes sure that if you (in future) forget to add `assert` you would get error. Thats really it - as we need to wait for support of abstract in statics - and as in tthe topic link i gave you - it might take a while...